# Transparent background of Winform in powershell

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

[image]

Here I have a form with a PictureBox in it. I removed borders and now I want to make the background of the form transparent, so when I launch the script we just see the image nothing else.

I am making a splash screen kind of project with an unusual png shape. I tried the "TransperancyKey = Color" thing from .Net but it doesn't work. I want it to run in PowerShell.

````
# Importing Assembly for Windows Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# Main form/SplashScreen Object
$SScreen                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$SScreen.BackColor            = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)
#$SScreen.BackColor = Color.Lime
$SScreen.StartPosition        = 1
$SScreen.FormBorderStyle      = 0

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile('./1.png')
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width = $img.Size.Width
$pictureBox.Height = $img.Size.Height
$pictureBox.Image = $img
$SScreen.controls.add($pictureBox)

$SScreen.Width = $pictureBox.Width
$SScreen.Height = $pictureBox.Height

# Open the main form
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe"
$SScreen.TopMost = $true
$SScreen.Show()

Start-Sleep -seconds 5

$SScreen.Close()```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without adding a picturebox to the form and simply use the forms own `BackgroundImage` property for this.

Make sure your image has transparency of course.

For this, I took your image and made all black transparent.
Because I copied from the web page, it won't be as crisp as yours, but it's the idea that counts.

Try:

```
# Importing Assembly for Windows Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile('./1.png')

# Main form/SplashScreen Object
$SScreen                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$SScreen.Width             = $img.Width
$SScreen.Height            = $img.Height
$SScreen.TopMost           = $true
$SScreen.BackgroundImage   = $img
$SScreen.AllowTransparency = $true
$SScreen.TransparencyKey   = $SScreen.BackColor
$SScreen.StartPosition     = 1
$SScreen.FormBorderStyle   = 0

# Open the main form
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe"

$SScreen.Show()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$SScreen.Close()
# tell Windows it can be removed from memory
$SScreen.Dispose()
```

Result:

[image: demo]